# How can I make a background image scalebale

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a banner `div`:

```
<div class="background" style="background: url(<%= @banner.image.url(:big) %>) no-repeat"></div>
```

and corresponding css:

```
#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 275px;
}

#banner .background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 275px;
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

uploader.rb:

```
version :big do
  process resize_to_fill: [1920, 280]
end
```

On smaller devices, the `background-image` is cropped, here are the screenshots. Full width:

[image]

And a resized window:

[image]

Is there any way to make the image be resizable when the screen width becomes narrow? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `background-size: 100% auto;`

Comment: Note: Use background-image property for inline css instead of background

Answer (score 4):

Just use `background-size: contain` for this

```
#banner .background {
    background-size: contain; 
}
```